# How to make the height of NSTextView always higher than the actual height of 20px?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstextview

I'm using NSTextView as a text editor, and I want to make it about 20 PX taller than the recalculation after the user enters the text.

That is, when NSTextView rolls in the end of the NSScrollView, there is a blank area that makes the user do not have to enter a return to make a blank line. In this way, the text of the tail will always be on the upper side to facilitate the user's visual experience.

How do you do this?

[How to resize NSTextView according to its content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654580/how-to-resize-nstextview-according-to-its-content)

I found some hints in this question, but the connection was invalid after too long.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize NSTextView according to its content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654580/how-to-resize-nstextview-according-to-its-content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `NSTextView` is nested inside an `NSScrolView` most of the times, you can play with the scroll view's margins.

The solution below is for storyboard-based app, which has a **minium requirement of OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)**:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: NSScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: NSTextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textView.layoutManager?.delegate = self
        scrollView.automaticallyAdjustsContentInsets = false
    }
}

extension ViewController: NSLayoutManagerDelegate {
    func layoutManager(_ layoutManager: NSLayoutManager, didCompleteLayoutFor textContainer: NSTextContainer?, atEnd layoutFinishedFlag: Bool) {
        guard let textContainer = textContainer else { return }

        let textRect = layoutManager.usedRect(for: textContainer)
        let bottomSpace: CGFloat = 20.0
        let bottomInset: CGFloat = (textRect.height + bottomSpace) > scrollView.bounds.height ? bottomSpace : 0

        scrollView.contentInsets.bottom = bottomInset
        scrollView.scrollerInsets.bottom = -bottomInset
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:** *how do I scroll the text view if I click on the bottom space?*

You can play around with [`NSParagraphStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsparagraphstyle) to add some after the last paragraph. Or you can use the Responder Chain and make view controller change the cursor position to the end of the text view:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    // ...

    override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
        let bottomSpace = scrollView.contentInsets.bottom
        let clickLocation = self.view.convert(event.locationInWindow, to: textView)
        let bottomRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: textView.bounds.height, width: textView.bounds.width, height: bottomSpace)

        if bottomRect.contains(clickLocation) {
            textView.moveToEndOfDocument(self)
        }
    }
}
```

If you want multiple text views with the same behaviour, time to design your own class.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This effectively creates a blank area, but when I click on the blank area, the focus of the TextView will not be at the end, which is different from the original performance. Is there any possibility of improvement?