# How to resize a NSTextView automatically as per its content?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift5, nstextview

I am making an app where a user can click anywhere on the window and a `NSTextView` is added programmatically at the mouse location. I have got it working with the below code but I want this `NSTextView` to horizontally expand until it reaches the edge of the screen and then grow vertically. It currently has a fixed width and when I add more characters, the text view grows vertically (as expected) but I also want it to grow horizontally. How can I achieve this?

I have tried setting `isHorizontallyResizable` and `isVerticallyResizable` to true but this doesn't work. After researching for a while, I came across this https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextStorageLayer/Tasks/TrackingSize.html but this didn't work for me either.

Code in my `ViewController` to add the `NSTextView` to its view:

```
private func addText(at point: NSPoint) {     
    let textView = MyTextView(frame: NSRect(origin: point, size: CGSize(width: 150.0, height: 40.0)))
    view.addSubview(textView)       
}
```

And, `MyTextView` class looks like below:

```
class MyTextView: NSTextView {

    override func viewWillDraw() {
        
        isHorizontallyResizable = true
        isVerticallyResizable = true
        
        isRichText = false
    }
}
```

I have also seen this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54228147/1385441 but I am not fully sure how to implement it. I have added this code snippet in `MyTextView` and used it like:

```
override func didChangeText() {
    frame.size = contentSize
}
```

However, I think I am using it incorrectly. Ergo, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm a bit puzzled, because you're adding `NSTextView` to a `NSView` which is part of the `NSViewController` and then you're talking about the screen width. Is this part of your *Presentify - Screen Annotation* application? If yes, you have a full screen overlay window and you can get the size from it (or from the view controller's view).

```swift
view.bounds.size                // view controller's view size
view.window?.frame.size         // window size
```

If not and you really need to know the screen size, check the `NSWindow` & `NSScreen`.

```
view.window?.screen?.frame.size // screen size
```

### Growing NSTextView

There's no any window/view controller's view resizing behavior specified.

```swift
import Cocoa

class BorderedTextView: NSTextView {
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
        
        let path = NSBezierPath(rect: bounds)
        NSColor.red.setStroke()
        path.stroke()
    }
}

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
        // Convert point to the view coordinates
        let point = view.convert(event.locationInWindow, from: nil)
        
        // Initial size
        let size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 25)
        
        // Maximum text view width
        let maxWidth = view.bounds.size.width - point.x             // <----
                
        let textView = BorderedTextView(frame: NSRect(origin: point, size: size))
        textView.insertionPointColor = .orange
        textView.drawsBackground = false
        textView.textColor = .white
        textView.isRichText = false
        textView.allowsUndo = false
        textView.font = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0)
        textView.isVerticallyResizable = true
        textView.isHorizontallyResizable = true
                
        textView.textContainer?.widthTracksTextView = false
        textView.textContainer?.heightTracksTextView = false
        textView.textContainer?.size.width = maxWidth               // <----
        textView.maxSize = NSSize(width: maxWidth, height: 10000)   // <----
        
        view.addSubview(textView)
        
        view.window?.makeFirstResponder(textView)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work (except for one minor thing). The [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextStorageLayer/Tasks/TrackingSize.html) from Apple was the key here but they haven't described the code completely, unfortunately.

The below code work for me:

```
class MyTextView: NSTextView {
    override func viewWillDraw() {
        // for making the text view expand horizontally
        textContainer?.heightTracksTextView = false
        textContainer?.widthTracksTextView = false
        textContainer?.size.width = 10000.0
        maxSize = NSSize(width: 10000.0, height: 10000.0)
        isHorizontallyResizable = true
        isVerticallyResizable = true

        isRichText = false
    }
}
```

That one minor thing which I haven't been able to figure out yet is to limit expanding horizontally until the edge of the screen is reached. Right now it keeps on expanding even beyond the screen width and, in turn, the text is hidden after the screen width.

I think if I can somehow get the <s>screen</s> window width then I can replace `10000.0` with the screen width (minus the distance of text view from left edge) and I can limit the horizontal expansion until the edge of the screen. Having said that, keeping it `10000.0` won't impact performance as described in the Apple docs.

Comment: Note: This answer is same as the accepted answer except for the way we calculate `maxWidth`.