# SwiftUI: Multiline TextField in Form

Tags: macos, forms, swiftui

I have a form to fill in new data. The last entry item "notes" should allow multiline text and should show a multiline textfield in the form. I use

```
Form {
   ...
   TextField("Notes", text: $notes,  axis: .vertical)
       .lineLimit(5...10)
}
```

to allow multiline text filed but it doesn't work within the `Form`. Outside the form is works as expected. Funny thing the multiline space is created between textfield and the buttons but the textfield stays small. Any ideas how to implement multiline text in Forms?

[image]

Comment: Adding `.lineLimit(5, reservesSpace: true)` after `.lineLimit(5...10)` expands the height of the textfield. That said, new lines can only be inserted with option+enter, and lines don't automatically wrap. Are you sure this is what you want? I would strongly recommend `TextEditor`. The problems you mentioned can all be fixed one way or another. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70225464/5133585), which is probably a duplicate target. Otherwise, you need to write your own `NSViewRepresentable`.

Comment: @Sweeper, at the end I ended up using TextEditor. I still don't like to have to make so many adjustments to have it fit into the Form. But it's doing its job and not harming the appearance a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import SwiftUI

struct FormView: View {
    @State var firstName = ""
    @State var password = ""
    @State var address = ""
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            
            HStack {
                Text("Name")
                    .frame(width: 100, alignment: .leading)
                TextField("Name", text: $firstName)
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Password")
                    .frame(width: 100, alignment: .leading)
                TextField("Password", text: $password)
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Address")
                    .frame(width: 100, alignment: .leading)
                TextField("123 NW Avenue", text: $address)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    .lineLimit(6)
                    .frame(height: 100)
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.clear)
                    .overlay {
                        TextEditor(text: $address)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. Have a `TextField` and set `foregroundStyle` to `clear`.
2. Overlay `TextField` with `TextEditor`.

The following picture shows my trial.

[image]

Comment: Looks promising, let me check it for my macos app.